# Can't download vcrun2008 winhttp wininet with winetricks

Tags: command-line, wine, winetricks

I'm trying to play ROBLOX on Ubuntu, but for some reason this error message keeps on appearing:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-11-16 14:31:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/ie5/Update/1/WIN98/EN-US/3725.exe failed
```

Does anyone know what to do? I'm using Winetricks with this command:

```
winetricks -q vcrun2008 winhttp wininet
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

This means Microsoft has deleted the file from their servers. Oh and they did that a long time ago ;)

If you look at the link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/ie5/Update/1/WIN98/EN-US/3725.exe you can see you are trying to get a windows 98 file named3725.exe for IE5 from their servers.

See http://www.playonlinux.com/en/issue-1142.html for a similar question.
The mirror mentioned does not work.

---

Here http://am.net/lib/tools/Microsoft/ie/5/ is one. That site also holds all the other files that you might need.

Comment: You probably won't find it, Rinzwind, Win98 EOL'd a while ago and Microsoft has recently been redoing *most* of their download links and a lot of current updates are screwed with the downloads (except for Windows' actual updater)

Comment: @ThomasW. I took that as a challenge >:D

Comment: It was a challenge, Rinzwind :P  It also made you succeed in making your answer more complete, so... it worked.

Comment: @ThomasW. sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

If you got 404 from downloading files from winetricks, you should upgrade it first.

If upgrade won't help, try to use the development version by running these commands in some dir:

```
curl -o winetricks https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
sh winetricks vcrun2008 winhttp wininet
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded vcrun2005 and vcrun2008 and a couple more of old stuff for some games just 2 or 3 days ago without problems, I used PlayOnLinux along with Wine everything installs fine. Try this one, works with me.