# How to fix W2KSP4EN.EXE - atmlib installation error in Ubuntu 16.10 64bit to install PhotoShop CS6?

Tags: 16.04, wine, 16.10, playonlinux, photoshop

I was installing Photoshop CS6 in Ubuntu 64bit, and whenever I try to install the "atmlib" package using

> winetricks -q atmlib

It gives an error of 404 NOT FOUND. Not only this package but also other packages-

> winetricks -q atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 fontsmooth-rgb gecko

Here's the output-

> winetricks -q atmlib
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2017-04-01
>   23:43:47 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please copy and paste terminal output into your post as Screen Shots are more difficult to read and can't be easily searched or parsed. Thank you for helping us help you! Note that the screenshot doesn't agree with the 404 error you are reporting so this question is likely to be closed as unclear what you are asking. For pointers see [how to ask](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The `winetricks` in the repositories is out of date, and doesn't know where many files have moved to. It's easiest to use the latest `winetricks` from github which knows where to look instead.

So, based on part of [@kenorb's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/786226/425479) to a related question, run:

```
curl -o winetricks https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
sh winetricks -q atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```